# JNI: should I call "ReleaseByteArrayElements" after I use "NewByteArray" and "SetByteArrayRegion"?

Tags: java-native-interface

I saw in other threads, that when your native JNI method gets a byte array and you read it into a C++ char array, you should eventually call `ReleaseByteArrayRegion`, in order to delete the copy you got.

In my application I don't get a byte array, but I rather create one, using `NewByteArray` and I set its values using `SetByteArrayRegion`. Then I call some Java method that gets it as a parameter.

The question is, whether the `ReleaseByteArrayRegion` method should be called here too. Won't it free my C++ data source that I used in `SetByteArrayRegion`?

Code examples will be appreciated!

Comment: This question has been asked before. See the answer at https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/pedantic-jni-question.387942